# $p$-adic completion of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$.

Tags: ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be prime. The $p$-adic completion of $\mathbb{Z}$ is the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of $p$-adic integers, and its elements can be thought of as power series in $p$. Is there a nice description of the elements of the $p$-adic completions of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$?

Edit: The completion of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ contains $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ of course. I think it should also contain the series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty p^iX^i$, so the completion is strictly bigger than $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The completion of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is isomorphic to the ring of formal power series with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ that tend to $0$ $p$-adically. Indeed, it is, by definition, the ring of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences $(f_k)$ of polynomials $f_k\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$. To be a Cauchy sequence means that eventually, the polynomials become congruent modulo higher and higher powers of $p$, i.e. all the coefficients of these polynomials must eventually be congruent modulo high powers of $p$. Suppose that for some $k_0$, $f_m$ is congruent to $f_{k_0}$ modulo $p^{100}$ for all $m\geq k_0$. If $d_0$ is the degree of $f_{k_0}$, then this implies that in all these $f_m$, the coefficients of $x^d$ for all $d>d_0$ are divisible by $p^{100}$. By applying this for higher and higher values of $100$, you see that the coefficients in the resulting power series tend to $0$ $p$-adically.

These kinds of rings are very important in [rigid analytic geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_analytic_space).

The completion of $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$ is just $\mathbb{Z}_p[[X]]$. That's easy to see by just looking at your Cauchy sequence of power series term by term.

Answer (score 7):

The $p$-adic completion of $\mathbf Z[[X]]$ is $\mathbf Z_p[[X]]$. To prove it, it suffices to prove that the map $\mathbf Z[[X]] \to\mathbf Z_p[[X]]$ induces an isomorphism on the $p$-adic completions. This is obvious because $$\mathbf Z[[X]]/p^n\mathbf Z[[X]] \to\mathbf Z_p[[X]]/p^n\mathbf Z_p[[X]]$$
is an isomorphism, both sides identifying with $(\mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z)[[X]]$ in a natural way.

However, the $p$-adic completion of $\mathbf Z[X]$ is the ring $\mathbf Z_p\left<X\right>$, the subring of $\mathbf Z_p[[X]]$ consisting of the formal power series $\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n T^n$ such that $|a_n| \to 0$ in $\mathbf Z_p$. It is a nice exercise in limits to prove it.

Such rings are known as *Tate algebras* and their study forms the starting point of *rigid analytic geometry* (which is to algebraic geometry over $p$-adic fields what complex analytic geometry is to algebraic geometry over $\mathbf C$).